# How to solve a callable error for dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to use :

```
dico=dict((x, list()) for x in list_days_s)
```

with `list_days_s` a list that have defined earlier.
But I get the error

> 'dict' object is not callable.

I have read that this error is often caused by a use of parenthesis instead of brackets, so I tried to replace them but it does not fix my issue.

Could someone please help me with this ?

Thank you a lot in advance !

Comment: You've used `dict` as a variable name for a dictionary, overriding its name for the built-in `dict()` function.

Comment: Find that variable and rename it.

Comment: You appear to have written something like `dico()` somewhere that you don't show in your question.